# Can I make the condition with the string?

Tags: c, if-statement

I am totally new in programming, so I opened CS50 course and started coding in c. (I am sorry, English is not my native language). I decided to create my own little programm,but on the first steps faced the problem, which I can not solve myself. If someone has some free minutes, give me advice please.

In my programm I am asking a question: Do you want to watch Overlord?
I am waiting for "yes" or "no". Each answer will lead to different results.
The first part of code is working, but the programm accepts any answer, like my "if" does not exist.
I do not understand what the roblem is that.
I am sorry if my question is stupid.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Do you want to watch Overlord?\n");
    string s = get_string("");
    if((s = "yes"))
        printf("How old are you?\n");
}
```

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Do you want to watch Overlord?\n");
    string s = get_string("");
    if((s = "yes"))
    printf("How old are you?\n");
}

Comment: You should use `strcmp`, not `=`, to compare strings.

Comment: You don't use `=` to compare integers either, but `==`.

Comment: `=` means "set the value equal to", x = 5 makes x be 5.  `==` is a comparison, "is left side equal to right side"  so `if (x == 5)` is how you test `x`

Comment: Note: How to compare strings **will be covered** in the course.  It'll all make sense soon.  In the meantime, yes `strcmp()` is your friend. It'll return 0 if the strings match.

Answer (score 0):

`if((s = "yes"))` tries to set the value of the variable `s` to `"yes"`. (It doesn't, but that's another answer.)

Comparisons between single values are done with `==`. But you're comparing strings and each character is its own value. You need to use a special function, [`strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) like so `if((strcmp(s, "yes") == 0)`. We check for 0 because `strcmp` checks whether the strings come before or after each other in the alphabet, and returns 0 if they're equal.

---

Your compiler should have warned you about `if((s = "yes"))`, but often C compilers have their warnings turned off. Be sure to turn your compiler warnings on.

[C compilers have many, many confusing options for compiler warnings](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html). `-Wall` does not turn on all warnings. A good mix of typical compiler warning flags is `-Wall -Wshadow -Wwrite-strings -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic`. It's also useful to tell the compiler which version of C to use, without it it might use the very old 1990 version. `-std=c17` uses the 2017 version.

Comment: Keep in mind a person learning a subject does not have the background to interpret missing or ambiguous words. You have written “`strcmp` checks whether the strings come before or after each other in the alphabet, and 0 if they're equal.” This is a compound phrase; it gives two things for “`strcmp` checks”, and the second is “`strcmp` checks 0 if they're equal”. `strcmp` does not “check 0”. It returns 0 if the strings are equal. You should reword that to make it clear to a person just learning C.

Comment: Also `if((strcmp(s, "yes") == 0)` is, at best, a sentence fragment. It is just there, in your answer, without anything saying why it is there or what to do with it.

Comment: Re “C has many, many confusing options for compiler warnings.”: The C standard does not have any options for compiler warnings. The switches you are writing about are specific to one compiler. The other two most common compilers have different switches. (One of them has a lot of overlap but still has differences.) And the one you are writing about does not use the 1990 version of the C standard by default. Its default is to use its own variant of the language that is not any version of the standard.

Comment: `-Wextra` is not a good option to recommend to new learners. It has a [special purpose](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73310743/298225), for knowledgeable programmers to scour their code for issues. It produces warnings for things that may be acceptable to the programmer, so a typical use case for it is to turn it on temporarily, compile, examine all the warnings it produces, determine which to fix and which to ignore, and then to turn it off for normal builds, even for normal debug builds.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thank you for the grammar fixes. I've found `-Wextra` to be very useful myself when learning, and I'm sure they'll find their mix. I would love to have a new-to-coding reference/tutorial about compiler warnings I could link to.